# button should fire the action until I keep the button down

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have UIscrollview in which I have placed images.I use the buttons(touch down) to move the position of the images by 5pixels  inside the scroll view…..Button fires the action only if I repeatedly touches the buttons ( it moves the images to 5pixels if I touches the button again and again) I want my button to fire the action until I keep the button down (it should moves the images  until I release the button)…

Is there any possibility to scroll the UIscrollview by means of button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to listen to the TouchDown and TouchUp events. When a TouchDown event is fired you start a timer (or other) that periodically calls a method, and when you receive a TouchUp event you stop it.

It might looks something like that:

```
-(IBAction)touchDownAction:(id)sender
{
    self.yourtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(aselector) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)touchUpAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([yourtimer isValid])
    {
        [yourtimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

(You just have to link your button with these methods via IB)